# Any better way to read and write 8-bit in Rust?

Tags: binary, rust

I'm writing a boolfuck interpreter and I need to convert something to 8-bit.

If I use a `Vec<u8>` to store `01100001` (it should be `0b01100001u8 as char == 'a'`), how could I convert it to a `char`?

If I input `Vec<u8>` (e.g.:`b"hello".to_vec()`), how could I convert it to 8-bit?

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: This does not exactly what you want but comes much closer: https://crates.io/crates/bitflags

Comment: It's *extremely* unclear what you are even asking. A `u8` **is** 8-bits — that's what the "8" means!

Comment: Boolfuck interpreter only input or output `0101` one by one, I can't give it `97u8`. I have to transform it to that format. A variable only accept one bit in Boolfuck. Sorry for my expression. @Shepmaster

Comment: So you want to convert between the _string representation_ of a number expressed in binary and its numeric value? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

`true` for `1`, `false` for `0`

`u8` to `Vec<bool>`:

```
let input = b"Hello, world!".to_vec();    
let input_stream: Vec<bool> = {
    let mut string = String::new();

    for char in input { string += &format!("{:08b}", char); }

    string.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()
        .chunks_mut(8)
        .map(|chunk| chunk.iter().rev().collect::<String>())
        .collect::<String>()
        .chars().map(|c| c == '1')
        .collect()
};
```

`Vec<bool>` to `u8`:

`output_stream` is something like `10001001...`, but in this case it's `true false false...`.

```
let mut chunks = output_stream.chunks(8);
let mut output = Vec::new();

while let Some(chunk) = chunks.next() {
    let mut chunk = chunk.to_vec();
    let mut char = 0b00000000u8;

    while chunk.len() != 8 { chunk.push(false); }

    for (carry_bit, flag) in chunk.iter().enumerate() {
        if *flag { char += 0b00000001u8 << carry_bit }
    }

    output.push(char);
}
```

A better solution to convert string to bit:

```
b"a".to_vec().into_iter().flat_map(|b| (0u8..8).map(move |i| (b >> i) & 1)).collect::<Vec<u8>>()
```

Comment: `if c == '1' { true } else { false }` is exactly the same as `c == '1'`. Expressions!

Comment: @Kroltan Thanks!